# How to convert a normal filter to multi filter on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to convert a filter into a multifilter on Angular 12 (TypeScript)

I tryed this...

```
resp.filter(((v) => v.toLowerCase().indexOf("'") > -1)&& ((v) => v.toLowerCase().indexOf("’") > -1))
```

...but doesn't works.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put your 2 conditions in the first callback :

```js
resp.filter((v) => v.toLowerCase().indexOf("'") > -1 && v.toLowerCase().indexOf("’") > -1)
```

Notes :

- it seems that `toLowerCase` is useless if you want to search `'` or `’`
- I am not sure if you need a AND or a OR here. Depends of what you want to do. a OR seems more appropriate if I guess correctly what you are trying to do
- `indexOf > -1` surely works but now, javascript defines the function [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) (from ES6) which will make the code more readable (think about the future you that will have to fix bugs in this code 6 months later)

I suggest this instead :

```js
resp.filter((v) => v.includes("'") || v.includes("’"))
```

Comment: Thanks!
My co-worker and I have taken 2 hours to resolve the error, we feel a bit silly now the truth ... Thank you very much again!